# Validating and getting data in a JSON file (All client side, no server) from form fields in extjs. Absolute beginner

Tags: javascript, json, forms, extjs

Please help me with creating my first extjs form with basic test and combo box fields. I need to validate and accept data from this form on the client side itself in a json file. No server side scripting needed. Also if you provide some good material to learn extjs it will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are several configs to use in field configuration. e.g. 'allowBlank, minLength, maxLength,regex,vtype, validator'.

'isValid' method in formPanel will check the validation.

'getValues' methond will get JSON value from the form.

Sencha extjs documents and examples in its official website are very good already.

Please see a simple fiddle example [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sta)

Comment: thank you. can you direct me a to an example though?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample example to load a form from a Json file please check my fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1snc)

For Learning.

1. First start with Sencha Docs.(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/)
2. http://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs/Introduction
3. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/extjs/

The Above tutorials are maily focusing on basics , If you really want to expert just go throught the  documentation.

Comment: thank you! but can you write an example where the data is fetched from the form and stored in  a local JSON file. That would help a lot, thanks!